# Get Ids that match specific column values for the same column Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following table:

- `id`
- `c_id`
- `ch_id`

I wanted to filter that list, to receive all the `c_id`'s that have all the IDs in a list for the `ch_id`.

A `c_id` can have several `ch_id`'s. If for example, the list contains '`2,5`' integers. I should get the c_id's which each one has at least the values found in that list.

For example, I get in returns `c_id` 3, because the following rows correspond to the query:

- id: 1, c_id: 3, ch_id: 2
- id: 2, c_id: 3, ch_id: 5
- id: 3, c_id: 3, ch_id: 6

`c_id` also has `ch_id = 6`, but it doesn't matter, because it at least need to have those ch_id's that are in the list. I have no idea how to approach this, any help will be appreciated.

I though about grouping the table by `c_id`, but the table might be very big and I think it might make the query very slow after some time.

I'm trying to achieve this query in LINQ/Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Worrying about grouping being too slow sounds like premature optimization to me. Grouping is the right solution, and possibly faster methods would depend on knowing a lot more details about your data.

```
var ans = from r in src group r by r.c_id into rg where desiredch.All(ach => rg.Any(r => r.ch_id == ach)) select rg.Key;
```